# How do you run a function on exit in C++

Tags: c++

I have a function that I want to run whenever my program exits:

```
void foo() {
  std::cout<< "Exiting" << std::endl;
}
```

How do I register it to be run whenever the program exists, regardless of when and why it exits - due to signal, exit() call, etc?

Comment: Not possible in all cases -- some signals bring down the process immediately whether you want them to or not. (e.g. stack overflow)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the aptly named [`std::atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) function in the `cstdlib` header:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void exiting() {
    std::cout << "Exiting";
}

int main() {
    std::atexit(exiting);
}
```

The system will maintain a stack of functions registered with `atexit` and call them each in the reverse order of their registration when either the `exit` function is called, or the program returns from `main`. You can register at least 32 functions this way.

Comment: That does not get called after a signal or a call to `abort` / `terminate`. (Says: register a function to be called at **normal process termination**)

Comment: @BillyONeal which is why I said "when either the `exit` function is called or the program returns from `main`"

Comment: "32" ? bizarre. "The implementation is guaranteed to support the registration of at least 32 functions. The exact limit is implementation-defined. " Oh well.

Answer (score 9):

I am answering as a Linux user, but all of this should apply to windows.

I had this similar question, so hopefully I can sum up previous answers and add my two cents.

Signals and `abort()`: `^C` and `^Z` can be "intercepted" to call your function before exiting, presumably with exit(). Signals `SIGQUIT` AKA `^\` and `SIGKILL` which has no key stroke cannot be intercepted. Here's an example for using the `csignal` header and a C++ lambda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //signal requires lam take an int parameter
    //this parameter is equal to the signals value
    auto lam = 
      [] (int i) { cout << "aborting" << endl; exit(0); };

    //^C
    signal(SIGINT, lam);
    //abort()
    signal(SIGABRT, lam);
    //sent by "kill" command
    signal(SIGTERM, lam);
    //^Z
    signal(SIGTSTP, lam);


    while(1)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Exit: Since I used `exit()` in my examples above, care must be taken here. If the function being run is a clean-up function that only needs to run once, perhaps a static variable `has_run` could be used. Or in the example above, `raise()` a signal that you can't intercept. But those tend to come with core dumps which just feels dirty. Your choice, here. An example follows

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //called with no parameters
    auto lam = [] () { cout << "at exit"; };

    atexit(lam);

    return 0;
}
```

Take note that c++11 added a `quick_exit` which has an accompanying `at_quick_exit` which act the same as above. But with `quick_exit` no clean up tasks are performed. In contrast, with `exit` object destructors are called and C streams are closed, with only automatic storage variables not getting cleaned up.

Answer (score 3):

You could put it in the destructor of a class with a global instance.

```
class SomeGlobalStuff {
    ~SomeGlobalStuff() {
          foo();
    }
    static SomeGlobalStuff instance;
};
// putting this in a single compilation unit.
SomeGlobalStuff SomeGlobalStuff::instance instance;
```

But like any other method, you have to remember that you cannot use any data if you cannot garantee that it still exists. Deallocation of global objects is done in a arbitrary order, so basically, you cannot use std::cout in the foo() function. atexit() is worse in this regard, because whether it executes before or after destruction of global objects depends on the compiler and compiler options.

And anyway, you still have to handle signals correctly. You have to choose which signals to handle and which to not handle (you most likely don't want to handle SIGSEGV). You cannot escape signal handling. And remember that signals may interrupt your program at any time (unless masked) so your data structures might be in a arbitrary state, in the middle of an update.

Comment: I believe there is language in the standard that says `cout` is valid everywhere (defined to be constructed first) but I can't find it right now. This also does not work for signals, `abort`, `terminate`, etc.

Comment: @BillyONeal: `abort` raises a signal (which you must choose to handle or not, just like i said), `terminate` is an entirely different matter. Also, maybe `std::cout` always exists, but `abort()`'s actions are defined to raise `SIGABRT` " and may include an attempt to effect `fclose()` on all open streams". fclose(stdout) will prevent std::cout from working.

Comment: Only on systems that have such a thing as `SIGABRT`. `fclose(stdout)` may or may not cause `std::cout` to stop working, depending on your CRT. The standard does not define the relationship (if any) between the standard console input/output/error streams and their C counterpart file handles. When I say that `cout` is always valid, I mean that it is not affected by the `the order of initialization of non-local static objects defined in different translation units is undefined` rule. Perhaps I misunderstood your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way (in Unix and Unix-like operating systems) to regain control after a process exits is to `wait(2)` for it. Short of a powerfail, kernel panic, or forced reboot, this should work:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>

int AtExit() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) return pid;
    if(pid == 0) return pid;
    pid = waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    return pid;
}

int main () {
  if(AtExit()) {
    std::cout << "Exiting\n";
    return 0;
  }

  std::cout << 7 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: You are moving the problem elsewhere : what happens if i kill this program ? As written, ^C on the controlling terminal will send a SIGINT both to parent and child.

Comment: This is a really creative answer (though it does have the commenter-noted issue that ^C will hit both). You can ignore ^C in this if you want, but you won't be able to ignore ^\.